# Change SqlDataSource ConnectionStrings value in code behind (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net

I currently have this code in the front of my ASP.NET page

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRecentJobs" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString_DEV_customer_support %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString_DEV_customer_support.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT job_id FROM time_recorder_jobs WHERE (deleted = 0) ORDER BY job_id DESC LIMIT 1">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Which works fine.

However, I want to set or define the value of 'ConnectionStrings' using the codebehind - based on a session variable.

My web.config contains:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString_DEV_customer_support" connectionString="server=REMOVED;port=REMOVED;User Id=REMOVED;password=REMOVED;Persist Security Info=True;database=dev_customer_support;Sql Server Mode=True;Allow User Variables=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="ConnectionString_LIVE_customer_support" connectionString="server=REMOVED;port=REMOVED;User Id=REMOVED;password=REMOVED;Persist Security Info=True;database=customer_support;Sql Server Mode=True;Allow User Variables=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

So I wish to set either ConnectionString_DEV_customer_support or ConnectionString_LIVE_customer_support in the code behind, depending on which server environment the user is on.

I thought something like this would work (but it does not):

```
Dim SqlDataSourceRecentJobs As New SqlDataSource()
If Session("Environment") = "LIVE" Then
strUseThisDB = "ConnectionString_LIVE_customer_support"
Else
strUseThisDB = "ConnectionString_DEV_customer_support"
End If
SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(strUseThisDB).ConnectionString
```

Using the code behind (I use VB, not C#), how do I set/define/specify which of my ConnectionStrings I want to use?

Just to add, if it makes a difference, I also want to set the SELECT in the code behind too.

Eg.

```
SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.SelectCommand = "SELECT time_recorder_jobs.job_id, time_recorder_jobs.user_id, time_recorder_jobs.operation_id, time_recorder_jobs.task_id, time_recorder_jobs.customer_id, time_recorder_jobs.farm_id, time_recorder_jobs.output, time_recorder_jobs.start_time, time_recorder_jobs.end_time, time_recorder_jobs.comments FROM time_recorder_jobs INNER JOIN time_recorder_users ON time_recorder_jobs.user_id = time_recorder_users.user_id INNER JOIN time_recorder_companies ON time_recorder_users.company_id = time_recorder_companies.company_id WHERE (time_recorder_jobs.deleted = @deleted) AND (time_recorder_users.company_id = @companyid) ORDER BY time_recorder_jobs.job_id DESC LIMIT 10"
SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.SelectParameters.Clear()
SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.SelectParameters.Add("@companyid", Session("CompanyID"))
SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.SelectParameters.Add("@deleted", 0)
```

Comment: Interested that you have a connection string that suggests Sql Server, but an Sql query that uses MySql's non-standard LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    SqlDataSourceRecentJobs = New SqlDataSource
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    If ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString_DEV_customer_support").ConnectionString Is Nothing OrElse _
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString_DEV_customer_support").ConnectionString.Trim() = "" Then
        Throw New Exception("Connection Error")
    Else
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString_DEV_customer_support").ConnectionString
    End If
    SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.ConnectionString = conn.ConnectionString
    SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.ID = "SqlDataSourceRecentJobs"
    SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.ProviderName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM time_recoder_jobs"
    SqlDataSourceRecentJobs.CancelSelectOnNullParameter = False
    Me.Controls.Add(SqlDataSourceRecentJobs)
End Sub
```

I use the Page_Init to load the DataSource